# loop of objects does not work in only on method- java

Tags: java, loops, object

Thr program seems to compile and work fine the only problem is on the AvailabilityBooks(String tittle) method that does not even loop through list "mathites" and does not work properly.I can't understand why this problem is occuring.I am new to programming and any help would be appreciated.Thank you in regards. :)

Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
public class MainLibrary {
    static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    public List <Student> mathites=new ArrayList<Student>();
    public List <Professor> daskaloi=new ArrayList<Professor>();
    public Student Scurrent;//apothikeuoun to antikeimeno pou brethike apo AnazitisiName
    public Professor Pcurrent;
    String biblia[]=new String[]{"2666","All About Love","Desert Solitaire","Disgrace","Geek Love","Gilead","A Good Man Is Hard to Find","The Handmaid's Tale",
    "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy","Infinite Jest","The Left Hand of Darkness","Lolita"};

    public void firstMenu(){
      boolean ch=true;
      int answer=0;
      while (ch){
        System.out.println("=======MENU========\n1.Make account.\n2.Login\n3.Exit programm.");
        answer=ChooseOption(1,3);



      switch(answer){
        case 1:
          MakeAcc();
          break;
        case 2:
          LoginSystem();
          break;
        case 3:
          return;
        default:
          System.out.println("Wrong input!!");
      }
    }
}
    public  int PorS(){
      boolean check=true;
      int an=0;
      while(check){  // check if student or Professor
        check=false;
        System.out.println("Are you a Student or Professor?    ~~1=Student || 2=Professor");
        try{
          an=scan.nextInt(); //an= account property
          scan.nextLine();
          if(an!=1 && an!=2){
            throw new InputMismatchException();
          }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException imex){
          scan.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Invalid Input");
          check=true;
        }
    }
    return an;
    }


    public void LoginSystem(){
      boolean check;
      int an,i,j;
      String name="";

      an=PorS();
      check=true;
      while (check){
        check=false;
        System.out.print("Enter username:");
        name=scan.nextLine();
        if(name.equals("exit")){
          return;
        }
        if(AnazitisiName(name,an)){
          System.out.println("Username: '"+name+"' does not exist.Type 'exit' if you want to quit ");
          check=true;
        }
      }
      if(an==1){
        Scurrent.login();
        Scurrent.LoginMenu();
    }
      else{
        Pcurrent.login();
        Pcurrent.LoginMenu();
      }
    }





    public int ChooseOption(int a,int b){ //basic diabasma epilogon apo a mexri b
      int an;
      while(true){
        try{
          System.out.print("Option: ");
          an=scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println();
          if (an<a || an>b)
            throw new InputMismatchException();
          return an;
       }
          catch(InputMismatchException aex){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!!");
            scan.nextLine();
          }
        }
    }



    public void displayBooks (){ //kanei display ta biblia k dixnei poia einai available
      int i=1;
      System.out.println("---------Library Books---------");
      for(String t : biblia){
        System.out.println(i+++"."+t);
        System.out.print(AvailabilityBooks(t)?"    |Available":"    |Not Available");
        System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println("13.exit");
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    }

    public boolean AvailabilityBooks (String tittle){ //true if it's available

      for (Student s : mathites){
          System.out.println("AAA");
          for (int i=0; i<s.books; i++){
            if (s.GetTittle(i).equals(tittle))
              return false;
          }
        }
        for (Professor s : daskaloi){
          for (int j=0; j<s.books; j++){
            if (s.GetTittle(j).equals(tittle))
              return false;
          }
       }


       return true;
    }




    public  void MakeAcc(){
      String name="empty";
      int password;
      int temp,clas=0;
      boolean check=true,upper;
      clas=PorS();

      check=true;
      while(check){ //username input
          System.out.println("Enter Username |5-12 characters used |at least 1 number and no more than 2 |at least 1 Uppercase letter    !!!type 'exit' if you dont want to create account.");
          System.out.print("Username: ");
          name=scan.nextLine();
          if (name.equals("exit")){
            return;
          }
          System.out.println();
          check=false;
          upper=false;//check if there is one upper letter
          if(!AnazitisiName(name,clas)){ //check if it's already exists
            check=true;
            System.out.println("This username already exists");
          }
          else if (name.length()<5 || name.length()>12){  //check username leangth
            System.out.println("Invalid length!");
            check=true;
          }
          else{
            temp=0; //count characters
            for (char p: name.toCharArray()){ //check if there are more than 2 digits
                if( Character.isDigit(p) ){
                  temp++;
                }
                if (Character.isUpperCase(p)){
                  upper=true;
                }
            }
          if (temp>2){
            System.out.println("Only 2 numbers are allowed");
            check=true;
          }
          else if (temp==0){
            System.out.println("Username must contain at least 1 number!");
            check=true;
          }
          if (!upper){
            System.out.println("Username must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter ");
            check=true;
          }
        }
       }
       System.out.println("New account ||| "+ name);

      if(clas==1)
        mathites.add(new Student(name));
      else if (clas==2)
        daskaloi.add(new Professor(name));

  }
  public  boolean AnazitisiName(String n,int b){//true if name is available  ||  b=1 then Student
    int a;
    if(b==1){
      if (mathites.isEmpty()){
        return true;
      }
      for (Student s : mathites){
        System.out.println("AA");
        if(s.GetName().equals(n)){
          Scurrent=s;
          return false;
        }
      }
        return true;
    }
    else{
      if (daskaloi.isEmpty()){
        return true;
      }
      for (Professor s : daskaloi){
        if(s.GetName().equals(n)){
          Pcurrent=s;
          return false;
        }
      }
        return true;
    }
 }
 public void printmath(){
   for(Student p : mathites)
    System.out.println(p.toString());


 }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MainLibrary l1=new MainLibrary();
      l1.firstMenu();

  }
}
```

Student class:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Student extends MainLibrary implements LibraryAccess,NetworkAccess{
      private String name;
      public int books=0;
      private List<String> titloi = new ArrayList<String>();
      public int connection=0;

      Student(String n){
        this.name=n;
        for (String s : this.titloi){
          s="Empty";
        }
      }
      public String GetName(){
        return this.name;
      }

      public String GetTittle(int k){
        return this.titloi.get(k);
      }

      public String toString(){
          String stat= (this.connection==0) ? " off" : " on";

          return ("\n\nStudent Status: \nName:"+this.name+ "\nConnection:"+stat+"\nBooks borrowed: "+this.books+" || "+this.titloi);
      }

      public void returnBook(String tittle){
        String temp;
        if (this.books > 0){
          this.titloi.remove(tittle);
          this.books--;
          System.out.println("Book '"+tittle+ "' returned succesfully! \n");
          }
        else
          System.out.println(this.name+",you have 0 books.What are u supposed to return. >:| \n");
      }

      public void borrowBook(String tittle){
        if (this.books < 3){
          this.titloi.add(tittle);
          this.books++;
          System.out.println("Book '"+tittle+"' borrowed succesfully!\n");
        }
        else
          System.out.println("Sorry "+this.name+" you have already 3 books.You have to return a book if you want to borrow another one. :)\n");
      }

      public void login(){
        if (this.connection==0)
          this.connection++;
        else
          System.out.println(this.name+",you are already logged in.\n");
      }



      public void logoff(){
        if (this.connection==1)
          this.connection--;
        else
          System.out.println(this.name+",you are already logged off.\n");
      }

      public void LoginMenu(){
          int an;
          while(true){
            System.out.println("1.Borrow book\n2.Return book\n3.Account Status\n4.Logout ");
            an=ChooseOption(1,4);
            switch(an){
              case 1:
                AnazitisiName("Chrisgate7",1);
                this.BorrowB();
                break;
              case 2:
                this.ReturnB();
                break;
              case 3:
                System.out.println(this.toString());
                break;
              case 4:
                this.logoff();
                return;

            }
          }
      }

          public void BorrowB(){
             int an;  //saves the answer from displayBooks
              this.displayBooks();
              while(true){
                an=ChooseOption(1,13)-1;
                if (an==12){
                  return;
                }
                else if(!AvailabilityBooks(biblia[an]))
                      System.out.println(biblia[an]+" is not Available.Borrow attempt failed!\n");
                else{
                    this.borrowBook(biblia[an]);
                    return;
                  }
                }
              }
              

          public void ReturnB(){//cannot find symbol problima me to books na lithei AMESAA!!!!!!!
              int an=0;
              int i,p=1;
              int btemp=this.books;
              if(btemp!=0){
                System.out.print("Your books: ");
                for (String s: this.titloi){
                    System.out.print((p++)+"."+s+"\n");
                  }
                System.out.print((btemp+1)+".Exit\n");
                an=ChooseOption(1,btemp+1);
                if (an==(btemp+1))
                  return;
                else{
                  this.returnBook(this.titloi.get(an-1));
                }
              }
              else
                System.out.println("You have 0 books borrowed.Return attempt failed.\n");
      }


}
```

Professor class:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Professor extends MainLibrary implements LibraryAccess,NetworkAccess{
    private String name;
    public int books=0;
    public int connection=0;
    private List<String> titloi=new ArrayList<String>();

    Professor(String n){
      this.name=n;
    }

    public String GetTittle(int k){
        return  this.titloi.get(k);
    }

    public String GetName(){
      return this.name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ("\n\nProfessor Status: \nName:"+this.name+ "\nConnections :"+this.connection+"\nBooks borrowed: "+this.books+" || "+this.titloi);
    }

    public void borrowBook(String tittle){
      if (this.books < 8){
        this.titloi.add(tittle);
        this.books++;
        System.out.println("Book '"+tittle+"' borrowed succesfully!\n");
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Sorry "+this.name+" you have already 8 books.You have to return a book if you want to borrow another one. :)\n");
    }

    public void returnBook(String tittle){
      if (this.books > 0){
        this.titloi.remove(tittle);
        this.books--;
        System.out.println("Book '"+ tittle+ "' returned succesfully! \n");
        }
      else
        System.out.println(this.name+",you have 0 books.What are u supposed to return. >:| \n");
    }

    public void login(){
      if (this.connection<3)
        this.connection++;
      else
        System.out.println("Sorry "+this.name+"you are already 3 active connections.You cant make another one.");
    }


    public void logoff(){
        if (this.connection<3)
          this.connection--;
       else
          System.out.println(this.name+",you are already logged off.");
          }


    public void LoginMenu(){
      int an;
      while(true){
        System.out.println("1.Borrow book\n2.Return book\n3.Account Status\n4.Logig\n5.Logout ");
        an=ChooseOption(1,4);
        switch(an){
          case 1:
            this.BorrowB();
            break;
          case 2:
            this.ReturnB();
            break;
          case 3:
            System.out.println(this.toString());
            break;
          case 4:
            this.logoff();
            return;
          case 5:
            this.logoff();
            if (this.connection==0){
              System.out.println("Logged off successfully");
              return;
            }
            else
              System.out.println("Logged off successfully.Connections: "+Pcurrent.connection);
            break;

              }
            }
        }

    public void BorrowB(){
       int an;  //apothikeuei tin apantisi apo displayBooks
       displayBooks();
       while(true){
          an=ChooseOption(1,13)-1;
            if (an==12){
              return;
            }
          else if(!AvailabiltyBooks(biblia[an]))
              System.out.println(biblia[an]+" is not Available.Borrow attempt failed!");
          else{
              this.borrowBook(biblia[an]);
              return;
            }
          }
      }

    public void ReturnB(){//cannot find symbol problima me to books na lithei AMESAA!!!!!!!
        int an=0;
        int p=0;
        int btemp=this.books;

          if(btemp!=0){
            System.out.print("Your books: ");
            for (String s: titloi){
              System.out.print(p++ +"."+s+"\n");
            }
            System.out.print((btemp+1)+".Exit");
            an=ChooseOption(1,btemp+1);
            if (an==(btemp+1))
              return;
            else{
             this.returnBook(this.titloi.get(an-1));
              System.out.println("Book '"+this.titloi.get(an-1)+"' returned successfully ");
          }
          }
        else
          System.out.println("You have 0 books borrowed.Return attempt failed.");
        }

}
```

LibraryAccess and NetworkAccess interfaces:

```
public interface LibraryAccess{


  public void returnBook(String tittle);
  public void borrowBook(String tittle);
}
public interface NetworkAccess{

  public void login();
  public void logoff();
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the `return` statement in your for loops. This exits the method and no futher loop iteration will be done. This happens in the `AvailabilityBooks` method. I think you want to iterate over all professors, students and books there.

Comment: also, you should re-check your logic. the only way to exit your checkStudentOrProfessor is to enter invalid input. that makes no sense

Comment: @Sebastian I know and that's what I want  but it doesnt seem to even loop through the if statement ...

Comment: what is the logic of your Availability Books have it to be available for the studen and the professor? Why you return false if the title is equal?

Comment: @Alex It is checking if the book is already borrowed.If someone (professor or student) have borrowed the book it should not be available.

Comment: @Omnni ah well okay

Comment: @stultuske The only way to exit PorS method is to enter valid input. if(an!=1 && an!=2) that's what this statement stands for. if answer is not 1 AND is not 2 an exception error should be occured.

Comment: @Omnni which is exactly what I mean. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

At Runtime when you are in AvailabilityBooks then this references you Scurrent Object. You can check this when you do `System.out.println(this)`
Inside your AvailabilityBooks.

That is the reason why you StudentList ist empty here and why it will not go inside your for loop.

### Solution

To fix this you can make the list independent from the MainClass Object so just do it static.

`public static List <Student> mathites=new ArrayList<Student>();`

Also there is a problem with the logic.

**Imagine the first title is unequal it will instantly return false and go out of the loop without checking the other books.**

So you compare the titles you can initial think it is not available and then when the titles are equal this means that it is available so you can instantly return true;

If there is no equal title in student and in prof then you return false.

```
public boolean AvailabilityBooks (String tittle){ //true if it's available

  for (Student s : mathites){
      System.out.println("AAA");
      for (int i=0; i<s.books; i++){
        if (s.GetTittle(i).equals(tittle))
          return true;
      }
    }
    for (Professor s : daskaloi){
      for (int j=0; j<s.books; j++){
        if (s.GetTittle(j).equals(tittle))
          return true;
      }
   }


   return false;
}
```

### Output

After the changes you will receive the following result if you borrow the 12. and the 10. item.

```
---------Library Books---------
1.2666
AAA
    |Available
2.All About Love
AAA
    |Available
3.Desert Solitaire
AAA
    |Available
4.Disgrace
AAA
    |Available
5.Geek Love
AAA
    |Available
6.Gilead
AAA
    |Available
7.A Good Man Is Hard to Find
AAA
    |Available
8.The Handmaid's Tale
AAA
    |Available
9.The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
AAA
    |Available
10.Infinite Jest
AAA
    |Not Available
11.The Left Hand of Darkness
AAA
    |Available
12.Lolita
AAA
    |Not Available
13.exit
-------------------------------
Option:
```

Comment: the tittle that is given as paremeter is one book from the library that it is being checked if someone else's has it. For what you are saying if I want to check all books I will go through a loop that will check every single book the library has.(check displayBooks method).Imagine that if I run the program the command System.out.println("AAA") will not even be printed..

Comment: Okay I will check this but obviously then there are no students in your list.

Comment: No error received.If you Make account a Student is being made and enters the list.And you cant Login without an account so to reach method Availability book there must be at least one Student object at the list.

Comment: In other methods the same loop is working properly.(for example printmath()).

Comment: I tried out to print mathites at index 0 and the result was out of bounds becaue there is no element at index0

Comment: did you create an object first?The programs begins with empty lists.

Comment: I did an account with make account first then I logged in and then I went into borrow book where the function will be called. And it was empty

Comment: So when making an account  the Student does not enters the list and that's what causing the malfunction..Thank y.

Comment: @Omnni I am also confused it will be added; I printed out the students after I added one.
But inside the AvailabilityBooks it is not available. But for example after login it is available printing there the size. 

So it seems in between there will be created a new list or for some reason the user will be removed

Comment: I solved it by doing your lists static so they don't depend on the object.
I think the problem begins when you assign your Scurrent Student. After this the list is empty probably because it checks for this Scurrent for a list.

When you Student and Professor list is static it is undependent from the object
@Omnni

Comment: @Omnni this references the current logined student or professor, so there is acutally no need for the loop. printout this, this is your current logined user